# cocoa NSScrollView not pass scrollWheel event to next responder

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, swift5

My question is, I don’t know why NSScrollView isn’t pass scrollWheel event to next responder.

I have to manually add the code

```
class MyScrollView: NSScrollView {
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.scrollWheel(with: event)

        // do something

        // If you don't use these codes, the next responder will not receive the event.
        if let responder = self.nextResponder {
            responder.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know how to fix that but I don't know why there has this problem.

Does anyone have official information about this situation?

Comment: Responder chain mean only the first object in the responder chain handles action (doesn't mean all object in the responder chain handle action). Your code is correct. I would use your approach or NSApp.sendAction: cause your next responder might not know scrollwheel. Also don't forget you should not override scrollview https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_9Scrolling

Comment: @MarekH The next responder knows [scrollWheel(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534192-scrollwheel), it's a method of `NSResponder`. "The default implementation simply passes this message to the next responder."

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Willeke Well, I created a Custom View and add a Collection View, the structure like (Custom View(NSView)) > (Scroll View) > (Clip View) > (Collection View).  I wanna my Custom View Class can receive the scrollWheel event. But the event alway stop to (Scroll View)

Comment: So, I override scrollWheel function to meet my desired needs, because next responder is NSView.

Comment: Documentation: [Responsive Scrolling in AppKit Release Notes OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_9Scrolling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marek H noted, if an object handles the event, then it typically consumes the event and does not pass it up the responder chain. In this case, if the scrollView scrolls, then it's superView definitely should not do anything with the scroll event.

Second, overriding scrollWheel(with) will turn off responsive scrolling.

Answer: What you really want to do is override `func wantsForwardedScrollEvents(for axis: NSEvent.GestureAxis) -> Bool` in your (Custom View(NSView)) class.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534209-wantsforwardedscrollevents

NSScrollView will respect this and forward the scrollWheel events when it doesn't otherwise use them to actually scroll or rubber-band. Plus it's responsive scrolling compatible.