# SwiftUI Nested Scrollviews problem on macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

**(If any Apple folks see this - I filed a feedback: FB8910881)**

I am trying to build a an SwiftUI app with a layout similar to the Apple Music app - Artist Page or like in the SwiftUI tutorial from Apple ([Landmarks app](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces)). Inside the app you can scroll vertically over list items and horizontally over all the rows.

[image: Apple Music App Scrolling]

In my app I have a list of rows inside a `ScrollView` (vertical). The rows itself scrolls vertical and contain a `ScrollView` and an `LazyHGrid`. It works on iOS but not on macOS.

On iOS I can scroll vertically through the list and horizontally through the row-items - in the Simulator you click and drag to scroll inside the app - works like a charm.

[image: iOS scrolling works]

On **macOS** however I can only scroll vertically if I am not over a row... I scroll via the magic mouse up/down/left/right. The row's Scrollview seems to catch the vertical scrolling... In the Apple Music app you can scroll up and down and left and right if you over the Artist Playlist row.

**Xcode 12.2 and Xcode 12.3 beta, macOS BigSur 11.0.1**

[image]

[image: macOS scrolling problems]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewProblem: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Text("Scrolling Problem")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Spacer()
            }.padding()

            ScrollRow()
            ScrollRow()
            ScrollRow()
            ScrollRow()
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollRow: View {

    let row = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200))
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Row")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: row, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(1..<7) { index in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ScrollViewProblem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollViewProblem()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Luffy - thank you for your check. Which version of Xcode/macOS are you using? I updated my description: Xcode 12.2 and Xcode 12.3 beta, macOS BigSur 11.0.1 and put a gif into my description... Still having this issue...

Comment: I am also hitting this same issue with very similar code. Compiled on 12.2 and running on 11.0.1.

Comment: Can confirm this bug on macOS 11.0.1 with XCode 12.2. Used SwiftUI App as life cycle.

Comment: Having the same issue, macOS 11.0.1, Xcode 12.2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found a workaround for the bug, although I hope it will soon be solved by Apple.

To my best understanding the underlying issue is that the mouse wheel scroll events are not forwarded from the inner horizontal scroll view to the outer vertical scroll view.

What makes it so frustrating is that there is the `AppKit` method exactly for that scenario: specifies whether the scroll events should be forwarded up the responder chain. It's called `wantsForwardedScrollEvents` and it's documented [here in the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534209-wantsforwardedscrollevents). Even though the documentation says it's for "elastic scrolling", [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028765/cocoa-nsscrollview-not-pass-scrollwheel-event-to-next-responder) shows how it's equally useful for passing the events up the responder chain for all scrolling events.

So what we need is:

1. Make a `NSView` that overrides the `wantsForwardedScrollEvents` and returns `true` for the vertical scrolling axis so that the vertical scrolling events are passed from the inner horizontal scroll to the outer vertical scroll.
2. Insert this `NSView` into the SwiftUI view hierarchy between the horizontal scroll and the vertical scroll.

The second point is a little tricky, but thankfully the truly amazing SwiftUI Lab blog has [a wonderful tutorial on how to do exactly that](https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/). Seriously, I cannot count how many times this blog has saved my sanity when working with SwiftUI.

So the final code can look like that:

```
// we need this workaround only for macOS
#if os(macOS) 

// this is the NSView that implements proper `wantsForwardedScrollEvents` method
final class VerticalScrollingFixHostingView<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content: View {

  override func wantsForwardedScrollEvents(for axis: NSEvent.GestureAxis) -> Bool {
    return axis == .vertical
  }
}

// this is the SwiftUI wrapper for our NSView
struct VerticalScrollingFixViewRepresentable<Content>: NSViewRepresentable where Content: View {
  
  let content: Content
  
  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSHostingView<Content> {
    return VerticalScrollingFixHostingView<Content>(rootView: content)
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSHostingView<Content>, context: Context) {}

}

// this is the SwiftUI wrapper that makes it easy to insert the view 
// into the existing SwiftUI view builders structure
struct VerticalScrollingFixWrapper<Content>: View where Content : View {

  let content: () -> Content
  
  init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VerticalScrollingFixViewRepresentable(content: self.content())
  }
}
#endif
```

Having that structure ready, we can use it in your sample like this:

```
import SwiftUI

// just a helper to make using nicer by keeping #if os(macOS) in one place
extension View {
  @ViewBuilder func workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS() -> some View {
    #if os(macOS)
    VerticalScrollingFixWrapper { self }
    #else
    self
    #endif
  }
}

struct ScrollViewProblem: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      HStack {
        Text("Scrolling Problem")
          .font(.largeTitle)
        Spacer()
      }.padding()
      
      ScrollRow().workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS()
      ScrollRow().workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS()
      ScrollRow().workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS()
      ScrollRow().workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS()
    }
  }
}
```

Verified on macOS 11.0.1 and Xcode 12.2.

*[updated based on comment by @marshallino16]*

You might encounter one SwiftUI issue after you've added the `NSView` into  your view hierarchy. The inner views stop responding to the change in the state of the outer view.

Using the terms from sample code here: if there is a `@State` variable in `ScrollViewProblem` that is passed down to `ScrollRow`, the `ScrollRow` doesn't always recompute on that @State variable change.

This issue is mentioned in the ["An Unpleasant Surprise" section of SwiftUI Lab blogpost](https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/).

Unfortunately, I've not found a direct workaround to make the `@State` propagation work again, so currently the best working solution I'm aware of (and been using myself) is to not pass the `@State` variable from the `ScrollViewProblem` to `ScrollRow`.

This means that whatever information you need to pass to `ScrollRow`, you must encapsulate it in the external object (view model, view store, whatever your architecture uses). Then you can pass this object to the `ScrollRow` and let the `ScrollRow` keep it and use it as either `@State` or `@StateObject` variable.

Comment: This is an amazing answer and can confirm it works for me too. Thanks so much for taking the time to share it.
Only issue was that it lead to some sizing regressions with getting the row to be centered in the scroll view. I worked around that by moving the view modifier up a level onto a `ZStack` so as to avoid confusing the scroll view.

Comment: Yes, introducing the additional wrapper might cause the previous SwiftUI structure to behave differently. After all, it's one more view, so if there was some particular sizing defined, it's not defined for that view anymore. Great you've managed to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately the wrapped scrollview doesn't react to viewmodel changes anymore. Did you experience this?

Comment: @marshallino16 Yeah, there's an issue in SwiftUI that causes the View to stop properly responding to state changes (recreating the body) after it's been embodied in the AppKit view. It's described [under "An Unpleasant Surprise" in the SwiftUI Lab blogpost](https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/). 

In my own project I've successfully worked around this issue by moving the `workaroundForVerticalScrollingBugInMacOS()` outside of the view encapsulating the @State. Basically, instead of calling it inside the ScrollRow I've been calling it inside the ScrollView.

Comment: @marshallino16 I've updated the answer to address the problem you've encountered. In your case a solution might be to extract the smaller viewmodel that is just for the scroll row and pass this smaller view model directly to the scroll row. This way it can keep it as `@StateObject` locally and use it for computing the body.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! I actually found a workaround (not ideal) where I set the content each time the representable view needs to be updated. In **updateNSView** > `nsView.rootView = content`

Comment: @marshallino16 Oh, that's also a nice approach, leveraging the updateNSView. I'll try it too.

Comment: It seems SwiftUI preview is broken when trying to use that fix :
`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

`LinkDylibError: Failed to build SentryDiskView.swift`

`Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`
`"ObjC resilient class stub for Peeled.VerticalScrollingFixHostingView", referenced from:`

Comment: Might be good to amend the post with @marshallino16's suggestion. I ended up reimplementing the same thing in my project because I hadn't seen their comment initially.

Comment: Adding this here for who needs it, make sure after implementing this you don't have a LazyHstack or LazyVStack in any of your scrollviews or you would deal with the error: 

> The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in
> Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window
> passes than there are views in the window.